# FileUtils.mkdir can not create a directory

Tags: ruby

I'm sure it is not a permissions issue cause it actually can create some directories.

Example:

```
FileUtils.mkdir "/tmp/foo"
```

works well

but

```
FileUtils.mkdir "/tmp/bar/foo"
```

fails with error

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /tmp/bar/foo
```

which does ot make sense to me cause i know it does not exists and that's why i want to create it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need `FileUtils.mkdir_p "/tmp/bar/foo"`

`mkdir_p` behaves exactly as `mkdir -p` on UNIXes - if some dir does not exists it will be created.

I bet there are no `/tmp/bar` dir and Ruby fails to create a dir into an non-existing folder.

Comment: Yes, that was it, `/tmp/bar` does not exists and i were expecting it to be auto-created by `mkdir`. Thank you for `mkdir_p`. SO is a best book ever :)